# Accessing getFilesDir()

Tags: android, directory

I'm just trying to access files in my app-folder.

/app-name/Download/myFile.pdf

My tries:

```
File fileDl = new File(getFilesDir(), "epaper.pdf");
if (!fileDl.exists())
{
   AlertDialog alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("nope").show();
}
```

getFilesDir() returns

**/data/user/0/app-name/files**

But the directory in my emulator says:

**/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/Android/data/app-name/files**

Is this the reason, why I can't access the dowonloaded files?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Your second path might be `getExternalFilesDir(null)`.

Comment: `my app-folder.

/app-name/Download/myFile.pdf` ?? That is not your app folder and it does not exist.

Comment: if (!fileDl.exists())
{
   AlertDialog alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("file not found: " + fileDI.getAbsolutePath()).show();
}

Comment: Thx, CommonsWare, this was the right way.

blackapps, sorry, I guess I just wrongly expressed the problem :-)